# i want to label count the value from 1 instead of zero

Tags: python

I want to make to function for ranking for variable and its rank can be used in the data frame.

Here is an example what I want:

`cs1['region__c'].value_counts()`

`Southwest         31`
`Midwest           10`
`Southeast         9`
`West              9`
`Mid-Atlantic      4`
`Northeast         4`

```
region__c               rank

Southwest         31     6
Midwest           10     5
Southeast         9      3
West              9      4
Mid-Atlantic      4      2
Northeast         4      1
```

Hence this rank can be used to replace say (Southwest to 6) and it can be done for multiple columns at once in the data frame.

ex: `cs1.head(4)`

```
name  region__c
sam   1
andy  2
adam  6
rohan 1
```

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: i have done label count encoding but in that it is using index for ranking and i dont want that i.e. it starting from zero instead of one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `pandas.Series.reset_index` with `to_numpy`:

```
s = cs1['region__c'].value_counts()
new_df = pd.DataFrame(s)
new_df['rank'] = new_df.shape[0] - new_df.reset_index().index.to_numpy()
```

Output:

```
              region__c  rank
Southwest            31     6
Midwest              10     5
Southeast             9     4
West                  9     3
Mid-Atlantic          4     2
Northeast             4     1
```